# Redips Drag and Drop content table content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly I would like to apologise if I am not providing everything as I am not sure how to.

I have using the redips drag and drop library with Javascript to drag and drop content within table.

This is what is been adviced on redips documentation in order to be draggable:

```
Here are minimal steps to enable content dragging in table:

put <script type=”text/javascript” src=”redips-drag-min.js”></script> to the head section
initialize REDIPS.drag library: <body onload=”REDIPS.drag.init()”>
place table(s) inside <div id=”redips-drag”> to enable content dragging
place <div class=”redips-drag”>Hello World</div> to the table cell
```

Redips documentation can be found [here](http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/).

This is what I have :

```
<td style="background-color: crimson; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div id="d1" style="background-color:crimson;color:#fff;" class="redips-drag" value="maths"></div></td>
```

this is wrapped inside a table which the table is inside a div called "redips-drag"

However the cell is not draggable after **refresh**

Like I said I know I haven't provided the full code.

However I was wondering if there is anyone who came to same situation ?

Any suggestions or guide would be much appreciated

Comment: You can find here all examples. https://github.com/dbunic/REDIPS_drag

Comment: I have tried these